# Want a succinct way of defining this particular set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $S$ is defined as being the set:

> $\{$
>   $\quad \{ (x, 1), (y, 1), (z, 1) \},$
>   $\quad \{ (x, 1), (y, 1), (z, 2) \},$
>   $\quad \{ (x, 1), (y, 1), (z, 3) \},$
>
> $\quad \{ (x, 1), (y, 2), (z, 1) \},$
>   $\quad \{ (x, 1), (y, 2), (z, 2) \},$
>   $\quad \{ (x, 1), (y, 2), (z, 3) \},$
>
> $\quad \{ (x, 1), (y, 3), (z, 1) \},$
>   $\quad \{ (x, 1), (y, 3), (z, 2) \},$
>   $\quad \{ (x, 1), (y, 3), (z, 3) \},$
>
> $\color{green}{\quad \{ (x, 2), (y, 1), (z, 1) \},}$
>   $\color{green}{\quad \{ (x, 2), (y, 1), (z, 2) \},}$
>   $\color{green}{\quad \{ (x, 2), (y, 1), (z, 3) \},}$
>
> $\color{green}{\quad \{ (x, 2), (y, 2), (z, 1) \},}$
>   $\color{green}{\quad \{ (x, 2), (y, 2), (z, 2) \},}$
>   $\color{green}{\quad \{ (x, 2), (y, 2), (z, 3) \},}$
>
> $\color{green}{\quad \{ (x, 2), (y, 3), (z, 1) \},}$
>   $\color{green}{\quad \{ (x, 2), (y, 3), (z, 2) \},}$
>   $\color{green}{\quad \{ (x, 2), (y, 3), (z, 3) \},}$
>
> $\color{blue}{\quad \{ (x, 3), (y, 1), (z, 1) \},}$
>   $\color{blue}{\quad \{ (x, 3), (y, 1), (z, 2) \},}$
>   $\color{blue}{\quad \{ (x, 3), (y, 1), (z, 3) \},}$
>
> $\color{blue}{\quad \{ (x, 3), (y, 2), (z, 1) \},}$
>   $\color{blue}{\quad \{ (x, 3), (y, 2), (z, 2) \},}$
>   $\color{blue}{\quad \{ (x, 3), (y, 2), (z, 3) \},}$
>
> $\color{blue}{\quad \{ (x, 3), (y, 3), (z, 1) \},}$
>   $\color{blue}{\quad \{ (x, 3), (y, 3), (z, 2) \},}$
>   $\color{blue}{\quad \{ (x, 3), (y, 3), (z, 3) \}}$
>   $\}$

Let $D1$ denote this definition.
$\color{white}{-}$
**I seek a reasonably succinct alternative definition (but equivalent definition!) of $S$.**
$\color{white}{-}$
My best attempt so far (with a necessary correction suggested by Meelo), is the following:

> Let $\; V = \{x, y, z\} \;$ and $\; N = \{1, 2, 3\}$
>
> Then, $\;S\;$ is defined as being the set:
>
> > $\{\; R\;\; | \quad R \;\subset\; V \times N$
> >     $\qquad\;\; \&$
> >     $\qquad\qquad v \in V \,\Rightarrow\, \exists n \in N \;\,\text{such that}\;\, (v, n) \in R$
> >     $\qquad\;\; \&$
> >     $\qquad\qquad (a, b) \in R \;\,\text{and}\;\, (a, c) \in R \,\Rightarrow\,  b = c$
> >     $\}$

Let $D2$ denote this definition.
$\color{white}{-}$
**Are $D1$ and $D2$ equivalent definitions of $S$ ?**

**If anyone can provide a definition of $S$ that is equivalent to $D1$, but reasonably succinct (the more succinct, the better), it would be greatly appreciated.**

Perhaps, an astute use of set operators could be used to arrive at such a reasonably succinct definition of $S$.

Comment: You should probably have $(a,b)\in R$ and $(a,c)\in R$ implies $b=c$ rather than the current line in your second definition. For instance, $(a,b)\in R$ and $(a,b)\in R$, but it is not true that $a\not\equiv a$ as your definition suggests.

Comment: @Meelo, You're right! (Oops!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you are familiar with the notation $A^B$ for all the function whose domain is exactly $B$, and their range is a subset of $A$, then this set you look at is exactly $\{1,2,3\}^{\{x,y,z\}}$.

Comment: Asaf, your answer is absolutely brilliant! ... That is lateral thinking at its very best!  Big thanks!